# AuthSub target path prefix does not match the provided "next" URL

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-calendar-api, google-authentication, zend-gdata

I am trying to use the Gcal API in PHP.

I am using the ZEND framework

```
function getAuthSubUrl($company) 
{
  $next = "http://$company.mysite.com";
  $scope = 'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/';
  $secure = false;
  $session = true;
  return (Zend_Gdata_AuthSub::getAuthSubTokenUri($next, $scope, $secure, $session));
}
$authSubUrl = getAuthSubUrl();
echo "<a href=\"$authSubUrl\">login to your Google account"</a>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I am following the google example almost exactly.

They do have `$next = getCurrentUrl();` in their expample but I am getting undefined errors when I try that.

Comment: I figured it out, I was using a subdomain that was forwarding to pages based on the subdomain. I guess Google tries to make sure that your $next page is real and mine were just forwards. Once I made $next the main domain it worked fine. 

I then just added some GET vars to the url to forward it back to the right place.

Comment: I would alao like to add that you should look at the ZEND documentation as it is much better than Google's. http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.html

Comment: Yeah, this i what I just ran into too!

Comment: Could you post the answer if it's solved?

Comment: @shaneburgess: Please post your solution as an answer (yes you can) and then accept it two days later? That will help to mark the question as answered. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, I was using a subdomain that was forwarding to pages based on the subdomain. I guess Google tries to make sure that your $next page is real and mine were just forwards. Once I made $next the main domain it worked fine. I then just added some GET vars to the url to forward it back to the right place.

```
//$next = "http://$company.mysite.com";
  $next = "http://mysite.com?company=$company";
```